# pop over is not coming in exact size in swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift

here i took view controller for my popover
but button(pop over button) is at the bottom of the screen so popover is not coming in its original height(as there is less space at the bottom of my screen). i need its full height. i am showing the pop over programmatically like this.

```
let popoverViewController:TimeViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TimePicker_ViewController") as! TimeViewController

        popoverViewController.index_val = index
        popoverViewController.t_value = t_value
        popoverViewController.delegate = self
        popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        popoverViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize.init(width: 250, height: 250)


        let popoverPresentationViewController = popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController

        popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up
       popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceView = button
        popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceRect = button.bounds


        present(popoverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Try setting the arrow direction to down so that the pop over is above the button?

Comment: yeah. @sweeper it worked!!  by adding this line popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the arrow direction to `up`:

```
popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up
```

You seem to think that this means the pop over will be shown on top of the button. But the property is called `permittedArrowDirections`. You are telling it to make the arrow point up. This will make the pop over shown below the anchor.

If you want to show the pop over *above* the anchor, you need the arrow to point downwards, right?

```
popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .down
```